# WPF button tooltip InitialShowDelay not working

Tags: wpf, button, tooltip

There is my button :

```
<Button  Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="3"  Width="40" Height="40" Command="{Binding NewConnectionCommand}">
                <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_add}" />
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
                <Button.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="5000">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Add connection</TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock>Open the dialog to create the new connection.</TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ToolTip>
                </Button.ToolTip>
            </Button>
```

I'm trying to set the initialShowDelay at 5000 ms like you guys can see, but the tooltip always show at the default time...

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: put `ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="5000"` on the button not on tooltip

Comment: I can't
Error 3 (Cannot set properties on property elements.)

Comment: what? there is something you are doing wrong.. see you can easily set on any element http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltipservice.initialshowdelay(v=vs.110).aspx. Also http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36930/Tooltip-service-and-tooltip-facility-of-WPF

Comment: I'm retarded I've tried to add the tooltipservice on <button.tooltip>...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to set `ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="5000"` on the `Button` not on the `Tooltip`. It is on Button you want ToolTip to shown with delay

```
<Button ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="5000>
```